# SqlDataAdapter Fill not timing out

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am running a Fill operation on a Dataset with Sql Server and I am running a long stored proc which takes several minutes to run. I am expecting to get a "Timeout expired" exception because I am setting my CommandTimeout to 60 seconds.

```
IDbCommand command = defaultConnection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandText = "Whatever";
command.CommandTimeout = 60;

SqlCommand sqlCommand = (SqlCommand)command;
Logging.Log(SeverityTypeEnum.Diagnostic, "CommandTimeout = {0}", sqlCommand.CommandTimeout);
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand))
{
    Logging.Log(SeverityTypeEnum.Diagnostic, "CommandTimeout = {0} {1} ", adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout, adapter.SelectCommand.Connection.ConnectionTimeout);
    adapter.Fill(dataSet, "MyDataSet");
}
```

The code above just carries on running and no exception happens. I have printed out the CommandTimeout and it is 60 in both places. I have also printed the ConnectionTimeout which is 5, although I don't think this is relevant. The defaultConnection referred to in the code is just a wrapper for SqlConnection.

I use a similar process with a SqlDataReader which works. Why is my Fill not timing out?

Comment: Have you tried with a lower timeout value? Just for the sake of testing?

Comment: Try not setting it, then it should default to 30 seconds.

Comment: If I set the timeout to a very low value like 1 or 2 seconds it does work. It is like the Fill doesn't time out once the query has started returning data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Fill is two-stage operation. The first is to execute the query and the second is to fetch the data. The CommandTimeout  only works during the first execution part.

The answer is to not use the CommandTimeout and instead use a  BackgroundWorker  to run the query asynchronously. You can then implement your own timeout which aborts the thread.

```
    private static readonly BackgroundWorker Worker = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerReportsProgress = true, WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };
    private static readonly AutoResetEvent ResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private static bool success;

    private static void Main()
    {
        Worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        Worker.RunWorkerCompleted += WorkerRunWorkerCompleted;

        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(60000);
        timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
        timer.Enabled = true;

        Worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        ResetEvent.WaitOne();
        Logging.Log(SeverityTypeEnum.Information, (success)? "Mission successful" : "We have a problem Houston");
    }
    
    static void WorkerRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Logging.Log(SeverityTypeEnum.Information, "Thankyou and goodnight");
        success = true;
    }

    static void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Logging.Log(SeverityTypeEnum.Information, "Time please Gentlemen, time!");
        ResetEvent.Set();  // aborts worker
    }

    private static void WorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // create SqlCommand, SqlDataAdapter and call Fill as before
    }
```